# Does quality of service (QoS) reduce the bandwidth that is available to “bulk” traffic?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, qos

If I enable quality of service (QoS) on my DD-WRT router, if there is no "preferred" traffic over the connection at a given time, will the “bulk” traffic still be limited?

Comment: I don't know DD-WRT well enough to answer authoritatively, but I'll say this: It would be a really crappy QoS implementation if it limited the bandwidth of any class of service when there's no congestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DD-WRT as far as I know uses standard Linux [`tc`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tc) (traffic control) commands—[See DD-WRT Wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Quality_of_Service#Detailed_breakdown_of_traffic)—and as a result only kicks in if you have network congestion.

[See Linux Traffic control overview](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/overview.html) for `tc` concepts. `tc` is often used in simulating congested networks (for example in WANEM, a wide area network emulator. Very useful if you want to emulate low bandwidth in your 10GE lab).

Once your network connection gets congested, it will guarantee resources for configured higher priority traffic.